# retrieve filename and content-type from base64 encoded image ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to retrieve the content-type and filename of an image which i am receiving in base64 encoded format.

here is the code which is doing a POST request with the base64 encoded image

```
require 'net/http'
require "rubygems"
require 'active_support'

url = URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/')
image = ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(open("public/images/rails.png").to_a.join)
post_params = {'image' => image }
Net::HTTP.post_form(url, post_params)
```

In the controller, I need to get the content-type and filename of this image. So first I am decoding it

```
image = ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(params[:image])
image_data = StringIO.new(image)
```

and then I am stuck!

I basically want to save this image using paperclip. Need some serious help!

**UPDATE :**
I can't send params for content-type and filename. I was just mimicking the client which is sending this (and i have no control on adding extra params)

Comment: Cannot you just add another post_param? Something like {'filename' => 'rails.png'}

Comment: no! The api I am developing for, doesn't send any other params. Only encoded image data. So, I want to know whether this is possible without sending any other params.

Comment: You're not thinking about using a user supplied filename to save something, are you? That's a bad idea.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short no! Its actually processed by the client application (ipad app) before I receive it directly from the user.

Comment: Good to hear. If the data is coming from an iPad, there won't be a filename anywhere unless the iPad user manually says "name it X".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could decode the raw bytes using one of the various ImageMagick libraries and then ask ImageMagick for the format. For example, with [RMagick](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/):

```
require 'rmagick'
bytes = ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(params[:image])
img   = Magick::Image.from_blob(bytes).first
fmt   = img.format
```

That will give you `'PNG'`, `'JPEG'`, etc. in `fmt`. ImageMagick checks the bytes for magic numbers and other identifying information so it doesn't need a filename to know what sort of image you're giving it.

As far as the filename goes, you're out of luck unless someone explicitly tells you what it is. The filename rarely matters anyway and you should **never** use a filename you didn't generate for saving anything; a user supplied filename should only be used to display the name to people, make up your own filename (that you know is safe) if you need one.

Comment: ya i think now filename shouldn't be an issue, as paperclip can associate with appropriate instances. All I need is content-type. let me try this out. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for this, I could get the format `PNG`, I can atleast set the content-type as `image/png`

Answer (score 0):

For the filename, why don't you just post that too, seems easier (`post_params = {'image' => image, 'file_name' => same_file_you_passed_to_encode64 }`). For finding the content-type you could use a library like `ruby-filemagic`.

http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-filemagic

Comment: The api I am developing for, doesn't send any other params. Only encoded image data. Is it possible to get the filename from just the encoded data? I heard its possible with php, I was sure there is a way out with ruby/rails

Comment: Unless the file name is part of the actual image data — which IMHO would be rather strange — I don't see how it would end up in the Base64 encoded string. Are you sure what you heard about PHP wasn't related to EXIF for example, where the filename can be part of the embedded data?