# Retrieve content_type and file name from Base64 encoded image string in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, base64

The jpeg image was decoded in a string saved in `uploaded_io`:

```
uploaded_io = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2....."
```

In rails 4 app, the image magick library has been installed and `gem mini_magick` is in `Gemfile`. From `uploaded_io`, we need to retrieve content_type, size and file name (no need to resize and manipulation of the image). We tried to use Ruby's base64 module in controller and there is no success (error and what decoded64 returns is not an image file):

```
require 'base64'

img = Base64.decode64(uploaded_io)
type = img.content_type #error
size = img.size  #error
```

There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955950/retrieve-filename-and-content-type-from-base64-encoded-image-ruby-on-rails) . But the ActiveSupport::Base64 is discontinued in Rails 4 and it can't be applied to Rails 4.

Comment: Instead of decoding `uploaded_io` using `Base64.decode64`, you should try to decode only the part that follows `data:image/jpeg;base64,`, in other words, decode `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2.....`

Comment: We did `img` = Base64.decode64.read(uploaded_io.sub(/.+,/, '')) (string started from `/9j/4AA...`) and img is assigned as `{Module}URI`. However `img.content_type` returns `''` and `img.size` returns Argument Error. What else we have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not speaking Ruby or Rails, I don't really understand your question, but I think you are trying to get information about a base64-encoded image and I can maybe help with that. I am afraid I can only come towards you from the command-line side of things, but hopefully you can Ruby-ize that...

Let's create a little image:

```
convert -size 50x50 xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append image.gif
```

[image]

To get information about an image with ImageMagick, you generally use the `identify` program from the `IM` suite, like this:

```
identify -verbose image.gif

Image: image.gif
  Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
  Mime type: image/gif
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 150x50+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 1-bit
    green: 1-bit
    blue: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 7500
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
  Colors: 3
  Histogram:
      2500: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
      2500: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
      2500: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
  Colormap entries: 4
  Colormap:
         0: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
         1: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
         2: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
         3: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: red
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 150x50+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2015-11-17T10:07:39+00:00
    date:modify: 2015-11-17T10:07:39+00:00
    signature: 48d1b973cce66f9a19f3b3738773a30f0519438d893cdfff2223e1941589e008
  Artifacts:
    filename: image.gif
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 325B
  Number pixels: 7.5K
  Pixels per second: 7.5EB
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-6 Q16 x86_64 2015-11-15 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

If I want to base64 encode that, I use `openssl` like this:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in image.gif

R0lGODlhlgAyAPEAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAACWADIAAAL+hI+p
y50Bo5y02juF3rz7D4adQ5YmgqXqKonuC3PnTD/sjbfxzsv1f8oJb73iDogkDZcp
o9OVjC6Y1Mrz+pFqD9VuBAvebLdebzg81pa7Z3Bauq62se9onDq/1pN3Zv65h9S3
9OcUCDQ4VGh0+JMotFjUWPOYE9kzSVOJc8mTObNJ1BnzGRS6MkpaWnKKmvqyytra
9AoV6zBLWxtyi5t7sSvS2/ALHAwyzFBscYycrLBs1ezxDB2dMT1SjXKtky22zdX9
9Q0eDjBOXi5wbpAOsa7Rjv4ez97+HmA/n7+PXx+PH8B1AtP5O9cv4D+DChEOLFdw
3MFwCQkulNiQ4sMXbxG7TdxWEeJFjxlBbszW8drHaiG/FQAAOw==
```

The point of my post is to show that you can then pump that base64 mess into `identify` to interpret it, like this:

```
identify -verbose "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhlgAyAPEAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAACWADIAAAL+hI+p
> y50Bo5y02juF3rz7D4adQ5YmgqXqKonuC3PnTD/sjbfxzsv1f8oJb73iDogkDZcp
> o9OVjC6Y1Mrz+pFqD9VuBAvebLdebzg81pa7Z3Bauq62se9onDq/1pN3Zv65h9S3
> 9OcUCDQ4VGh0+JMotFjUWPOYE9kzSVOJc8mTObNJ1BnzGRS6MkpaWnKKmvqyytra
> 9AoV6zBLWxtyi5t7sSvS2/ALHAwyzFBscYycrLBs1ezxDB2dMT1SjXKtky22zdX9
> 9Q0eDjBOXi5wbpAOsa7Rjv4ez97+HmA/n7+PXx+PH8B1AtP5O9cv4D+DChEOLFdw
> 3MFwCQkulNiQ4sMXbxG7TdxWEeJFjxlBbszW8drHaiG/FQAAOw=="
Image:
  Base filename: FQAAOw==
  Format: GIF (CompuServe graphics interchange format)
  Mime type: image/gif
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 150x50+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 1-bit
    green: 1-bit
    blue: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 7500
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 85 (0.333333)
      standard deviation: 120.208 (0.471405)
      kurtosis: -1.5
      skewness: 0.707107
      entropy: 0.918296
  Colors: 3
  Histogram:
      2500: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
      2500: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
      2500: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
  Colormap entries: 4
  Colormap:
         0: (255,  0,  0) #FF0000 red
         1: (  0,255,  0) #00FF00 lime
         2: (  0,  0,255) #0000FF blue
         3: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: red
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 150x50+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2015-11-17T10:12:05+00:00
    date:modify: 2015-11-17T10:12:05+00:00
    signature: 48d1b973cce66f9a19f3b3738773a30f0519438d893cdfff2223e1941589e008
  Artifacts:
    filename: data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhlgAyAPEAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAACWADIAAAL+hI+p
y50Bo5y02juF3rz7D4adQ5YmgqXqKonuC3PnTD/sjbfxzsv1f8oJb73iDogkDZcp
o9OVjC6Y1Mrz+pFqD9VuBAvebLdebzg81pa7Z3Bauq62se9onDq/1pN3Zv65h9S3
9OcUCDQ4VGh0+JMotFjUWPOYE9kzSVOJc8mTObNJ1BnzGRS6MkpaWnKKmvqyytra
9AoV6zBLWxtyi5t7sSvS2/ALHAwyzFBscYycrLBs1ezxDB2dMT1SjXKtky22zdX9
9Q0eDjBOXi5wbpAOsa7Rjv4ez97+HmA/n7+PXx+PH8B1AtP5O9cv4D+DChEOLFdw
3MFwCQkulNiQ4sMXbxG7TdxWEeJFjxlBbszW8drHaiG/FQAAOw==
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 325B
  Number pixels: 7.5K
  Pixels per second: 7.5EB
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.2-6 Q16 x86_64 2015-11-15 http://www.imagemagick.org
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Ei0.gif
```

Or, you can use `convert` and re-create the image from its base64-encoded state like this:

```
{ echo "data:image/png;base64,"; openssl enc -base64 -in image.png; } | convert inline:- decoded.gif
```

Comment: `Mark Setchell`, what I am trying to do is to save the encoded64 string back to a jpeg file on the server (no need to display the image). This seems to be the last step on your post (I am newbie to 'IM`. The `echo` seems to be displaying the image). I am not sure that creating image based on the encoded64 string is necessary before saving it. Is there a way I can process the encoded64 string with Base64 and save it directly in jpeg format which is the original format of the file?